# Pass angular value to common JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to pass a value from angular scope to  common JavaScript.

The JavaScript is like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var epaycode = null;
var epaybuysum  = null;
paymentwindow = new PaymentWindow({
'merchantnumber': epaycode,
'amount': epaybuysum,
'currency': "DKK",
'windowstate': "4",
'paymentcollection': "1",
'iframeheight': "250",
'iframewidth': "500"
});
paymentwindow.append('payment-div');
setTimeout(function(){
    paymentwindow.open();
}, 1000);
```

The angular controller code is like this

```
    $scope.showpay = function () {
    $window.epaybuysum = $scope.buysum * 100;
    $window.epaycode = $scope.ePayCode;
};
```

The Angular showpay() function is called after the common JavaScript is initialized. The buysum and ePayCode is set earlier in the program. They have value and is tested with console.log().

Why doesn't the epaybuysum and epaycode getting transferred to the common JavaScript?
Is there any other solutions to passing values to common JavaScript from Angular controllers?

Comment: Have you debugged `showpay` function? Does it hit those lines of code setting to `$window`?

Comment: if `ePayCode` is declared globally then you should be able to directly assign the value `ePayCode =  $scope.buysum * 100;`

Comment: The showpay hits the $window code..

Comment: How do I declare the ePayCode and sum as globally??

Comment: if they're not declared in a function, then they are global. at the moment they are global

Comment: I tried with  the ePayCode = $scope.buysum * 100; in the Angular controller, at that didn't change the value in the common JavaScript..

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/lQiXpObbWuG84CNbcZt2?p=preview

```
 <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
      <input ng-model="buyCode">
      <input ng-model="buySum">
      <p>{{buyCode}} ... {{buySum}}</p>

      <button ng-click="showPay()">call showPay</button>
 </div>

 <button onclick="buttonClick()">Console.log</button>
```

The first button calls your showPay function(the one on scope). The second button calls console.log (outside the angular controller, simple js). For this simple usecase it seems to work as expected. How are you calling showPay function?

Comment: It seems like I have a timing issue with this.. Could I call a common JavaScript function from the Angular Controller?

Comment: yes. with $window you have access to all globally defined js (including functions). So you can do: $window.myFunction() -- if myFunction is declared at top level(not within another function)

Comment: That woks great.. Thak you!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(function (angular, epaycode) {  
  'use strict';  
  var module = angular.module('abc', []);  
  //Your controller etc.  
  }  
})(angular, epaycode);
```

**Updated**
The plunker in the comments section shows how you can do this.

Comment: Do you have a Fiddler or Github example of this?

Comment: As I understand the solution, the data is send from common JavaScript ot angular?? Correct me is Im wrong?

Comment: Yes. You are correct. The variable test in the plunker is a simple JS variable and is being injected into Angular.